# Rewriting an equation as a set of inequalities

Tags: matrices, inequality, polytopes, linearization

I have a set $\\{x_1,x_2 \dots , x_d \in \mathbb{R} : |x_1| + |x_2| + \dots + |x_d| \leq 1 \\}$ and i would like to rewrite it as $\\{ u \in \mathbb{R}^d : Au \leq \textbf{1} \\}$ , where $\textbf{1}$ is a vector with each coordinate being 1 and $A$ only has integer entries.

I do need help finding the matrix $A$.

Comment: You should first tell us about the effort you made.

Comment: Hint: Think about how you would rewrite $\lvert x \rvert \leq 1$.

Comment: Squaring something seems impossible. So i thought about rewriting the absolute value of each $x_k$ as + or -. But one would need $2^d$ inequalities in total for that.

Comment: Ah. I didn't notice the $d$, sry... . Makes it harder.

Comment: Maybe you should look for duplicates on this side. I've already found some. Just google "rewrite 1-norm"

Answer (score 1):

Maybe I oversimplify something in the question, but is this what you are looking for:

$d=1$:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
-1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 
\end{bmatrix}
\le 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$d=2$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1\\
-1 &1 \\
1 &-1\\
-1 &-1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2
\end{bmatrix}
\le 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1\\
1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$d=3$:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1 &1 &1\\
-1 &1 &1\\
1 &-1&1\\
-1 &-1&1\\
1 &1 &-1\\
-1 &1 &-1\\
1 &-1&-1\\
-1 &-1&-1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
x_1 \\
x_2 \\
x_3
\end{bmatrix}
\le 
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
1\\
1 \\
1\\
1 \\
1\\
1 \\
1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
and for general $d$, the matrix $A$ is a $d \times 2^d$ -matrix where in the $2^d$ rows you have the $2^d$ possible arrangements of $d$ values, each $\pm 1$.

The background of this is that $\{x_1,x_2 \dots , x_d \in \mathbb{R} : |x_1| + |x_2| + \dots + |x_d| \leq 1 \}$ defines a volume which is bounded by $2^d$ hyperplanes, each of which can be expressed by writing your equation in one of the $2^d$ orthants, which in turn means that for each absolute value, once $|x| = x$ holds (for positive $x$), and once  $|x| = -x$ holds (for negative $x$).